# Reducing elasticsearch's index size

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I currently have a large amount of log files being analyzed by Logstash, and therefore a consequent amount of space being used in Elasticsearch. 
However, a lot of this data is useless to me, as everything is not being displayed in Kibana.

So I'm wondering: is there a way to keep the index size minimal and only store matching events?

**Edit:** Perhaps I am being unclear on what I would like to achieve. I have several logs that fall under different categories (because they do not serve the same purpose and are not built the same way). I created several filter configuration files that correspond to these different types of logs.

Currently, all the data from all my logs is being stored in Elasticsearch. For example, say I am looking for the text "cat" in one of my logs, the event containing "cat" will be stored, but so will the other 10,000 lines. I want to avoid this and only store this 1 event in Elasticsearch's index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not really given much information to go on, but as I see it you have 2 choices, you can either update your logstash filters so that you only send the data you're interested in to elasticsearch. You can do this by having [conditional](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration#conditionals) logic to "[drop](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/drop) {}" certain events. Or you could [mutate](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#remove_field) { remove_field } to get rid of individual fields within certain events.

You other choice would be to close/delete old indexes in your elasticsearch database, this would reduce the amount of information occupying heap space, and would have an immediate effect, while my first option would only affect future logs. The easiest way to close/delete old indexes is to use [curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator).

EDIT:

From your further question I would suggest:

- On your input, add a tag like "drop" to all your inputs
- As part of each [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok#remove_tag) you can remove a tag on a successful match, so when the grok works, remove the drop tag
- As part of your output, put conditional logic around the output, so that you only
  save records without the drop tag on them, eg:

`output { if "drop" not in [tags] { etc } }`

Comment: I agree with @Rumbles given the few information available, that would be the solutions you can consider!

Comment: Please excuse me for not giving much information, but I basically have several lines in my log files that I do not need, and I just want to control what is being stored in Elasticsearch. I want my ES index to only include text that has been matched by the regular expressions I created. I thank you for your suggestion, but the problem is that I have several filter files for different types of log files. What may not match for a type may match for another.

Comment: So basically what I am trying to do is to drop anything that matches with none of my regular expressions

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I needed, I have accepted your answer. Thank you!